# Laravel Livewire queues Serialization is not allowed

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-livewire

I try to load multiple images through the laravel queue as follows:

**Controller:**

```
foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGaleria) {

        $imagenes = $pathGaleria;
        $nombre = Str::random(10) . $imagenes->getClientOriginalName();

        $ruta = public_path() . '\imagenesPropiedades/' . $nombre;

        dispatch(new ProcesarImagenes($pathGaleria, $ruta));

        $img = imgPropiedades::create([
            'url' => '/imagenesPropiedades/' . $nombre,
            'property_id' => $this->propiedadId
        ]);
    }
```

**Job:**

```
public $pathGaleria;
public $ruta;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($pathGaleria, $ruta)
{
    $this->pathGaleria = $pathGaleria;
    $this->ruta = $ruta;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $img = $this->pathGaleria;
    $rut = $this->ruta;
    //make recibe la imagen
    Image::make($img)
    ->resize(800, null, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    })
    ->save($rut);
}
```

I get the following error: Serialization of 'Livewire\TemporaryUploadedFile' is not allowed.

Any suggestion will be of great value to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to pass the `getRealPath()` of the temporary file and later use `file_get_contents()` and continue from there onward.

e.g.

`dispatch(new ProcesarImagenes($pathGaleria->getRealPath(), $ruta));`

under your job **handle()**

`$img = file_get_contents($this->pathGaleria);`

Also, make sure to use `queue:listen` on your local environment, that way you don't have to restart queue after making changes to the Job file.

Comment: What happens if the file is deleted before the job is processed? Would it be a bad idea if I pass the file in base64 (or another serialized format) to the job?

Comment: Wouldn't work if using a dedicated jobs server as temp file is stored on main web server